# What is setting the double slash in ld output?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, ld

Looking for the gps library with the following command

> ld -lgps --verbose

I get the following output

```
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so succeeded
-lgps (//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so)
librt.so.1 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so
found librt.so.1 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
libdbus-1.so.3 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so
found libdbus-1.so.3 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3
libstdc++.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so
```

What is setting the double slash?

Comment: Is the library in the system's search path?

Comment: This is my search path `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/root/bin`  I don't believe the lib should be in the search path

Comment: The ldconfig command produce the following output:
`ldconfig -p | grep gps
        libgps.so.22 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libgps.so.22`

Comment: Doesn't look like the library is in the search path, try using `-L` to link the directory the library is in, like:  `ld --verbose -L </usr/local/lib/libgps.so.22> -lgps`

Comment: It all fails. `attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libgps.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libgps.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgps.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libgps.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libgps.a failed`

Comment: symbolic link `libgps.so --> libgps.so.22.0.0` works.  But what about another system.  Should this be already set?

Comment: You can try adding a symbolic link to your library path, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Why do you care?  The system treats the leading `//` just like a single `/`.  If you're having problems finding libraries, this is not the cause.